# Need help in identifying movie with a boy who can turn into a tree, and a girl from centuries ago

Tags: giniro-no-kami-no-agito

I saw this movie within the past few years. It was an awesome movie but I can't for the life of me remember the name!

Here is what I remember:

- A boy finds a girl sleeping in a glass pod underwater with thousands of others.
- He takes her to his village to help her recover. His village is connected by bridges to a dangerous, carnivorous forest on one side, and an industrialized desert on the other side.
- The boy's father is slowly becoming a tree.
- It turns out that the girl is from the same civilization, the apocalypse destroyed much of the world, and the people of her city were preserved in pods underwater. She came back to life hundreds of years in the future to a low-tech society.
- The people of her time used Ribbon (pronounced Ri-BONE) technology in much the same way we use Apple Watches and Google Glass. It's like a cross between a holographic smartphone and a necklace. Or bracelet(?) I forgot.
- The girl and anyone else who has come back from that time, is viewed as dangerous and is killed by bounty hunters from outside the village. They collect their Ribbons as trophies, but the bounty hunters can't use them because the Ribbon is bound to its user.

Here, the story gets a little fuzzy:

- The girl ends up riding on a train to the industrial desert city. She is valuable to them somehow.
- The city has huge steampunk beasts used for war.
- The boy and girl end up in a volcano base which has mechanical legs and can move.
- The boy turns into a huge tree to help her escape the volcano.

I really, really liked this movie. Can you tell me what it is?

Answer (score 5):

**Origin: Spirits of the Past**

I finally Googled "walking volcano anime" and found [Origin: Spirits of the Past!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1140/Giniro_no_Kami_no_Agito)

[image]

I kept Googling "ribbon phone", "ribon phone", and kept getting some other anime. I kept thinking it was Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind, but the art styles were totally different. Maybe I thought it was a Miyazaki film because of the story's environmental message.